# 6.0.7 Debian timeout if more connections at once

Tags: linux, debian, timeout

We are a some devs working on a Debian server.
We are all connecting from one IP.

So basically the server handles a lot of requests from the same IP.
Now what happens from time to time, is that we get a timeout. 
It feels like [fail2ban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban), if you input the wrong password for several times.
But it's not.

There is no firewall restriction on ports or sockets.

Could it be some kind of kernel maximum to TCP/IP connections?
**top** says that there is no strain at all. (cpu, ram etc...).

The web-server is an [AOLServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOLserver).
There are definitely no issues with it.

Version: **6.0.7 Debian**

The same goes for SSH as you can see it's not application related but rather OS related.

**We all use Debian as clients as well. 
If people connect from a windows machine there aren't problems.**

Thankful for all suggestions.
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: look maybe at ulimit, there are now inside the kernel some limitation to avoid denial of service that can be activated I know I add a similar issue on a xfce ubuntu but it really depends of the kernel and the ulimit

Comment: good point, I will check on that.

Comment: What does a wireshark or tcpdump network trace look like from both ends when the problem occurs?

Comment: @mindthemonkey I'll test that and report afterwards. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error anymore... But I'm sure it will come back again. Meanwhile I'll try to find the problem in networking with tcpdump.